# Can't connect to Online Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python-2.7, sharepoint, office365

I'am trying to display all sharepoint's list name but i'am getting this error :

**No handlers could be found for logger "office365.runtime.auth.saml_token_provider.SamlTokenProvider._process_service_token_response"**

This is my code :

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
url = 'https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username='username@abc.com'
                                  ,password ='password'):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    lists = ctx.web.lists
    ctx.load(lists)
    ctx.execute_query()
    for l in lists:
       print(l.properties["Title"])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found a solution to get data for specific sharepoint List

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
import json
import csv
import pandas

authcookie = Office365('https://abc.sharepoint.com/', username='username', password='password').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/SitesName/', authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('ListName')
#print(sp_list)
data = sp_list.GetListItems(fields=['FieldName1','FieldName2'])
c = pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Does not works with 365, no option for client_id and client_secret

Answer (score 2):

I tested below code here with python 2.7 and it works well.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

tenant_url= "https://company.sharepoint.com"
site_url="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sname"    

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(tenant_url)    

if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("abc@company.onmicrosoft.com","mypassword"):
   ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
   lists = ctx.web.lists
   ctx.load(lists)
   ctx.execute_query()

   for l in lists:
       print(l.properties["Title"])

else:
   print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

Result:

[image]

If this is related to ADFS, please refer to this closed question:

- https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/85

BR

Comment: i don't know why im getting this error :
**Exception has occurred: KeyError
'FedAuth'**